# iOS to JAX-RS : large data and timeout

Tags: ios, jax-rs, alamofire, nsurlsession

I'm using `URLSession` and requests (wrapped by `Alamofire`) on iOS side to PUT/POST large data to my JAX-RS server.

My JAX-RS endpoint consumes JSON, but it can be up to 5 MB large, so on bad networks, it can take a while.

To avoid any timeout on the iOS side (that is my primary problem), I know I can use a big timeout (let's say one day).

My questions are :

1. I have the belief that setting such a timeout could cause a "doomed from the start" request to fail only after one day, preventing my code to cleverly retry at the right time. Is this belief true and why?
2. Server-side, I know I could use async-response and stream mechanisms, retrieve the full JSON `String`, parse it to get my request parameters... But as it introduces a lot of boilerplate and some annoying adaptations in the target legacy server project, is there an alternative so that the client receives something that resets the idle [timeout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/1418229-timeoutinterval) from the `NSURLRequest` ?
3. Is there any alternative on the iOS side? For example, I had the intuition using `NSURLSessionUploadTask` could help but I have not clue it does indeed.